# Text from flash content

Tags: flash, image-processing, ocr

I am currently building a pet project just to kill some time (and learn a couple of things).

So the question at hand is: I want to capture text from inside a dynamically loaded flash content (pretty much, a scrabble-like game that puts letters on 10X10 array from which you get to pick). The requested functionality is to recreate this array on a programming language.

Since this will be for completely academic purposes, window placement, focus, permissions etc do not matter (it will be only run by me in a completely controlled environment so no need to consider deployment). Also the language used does not matter (any answer including image analysis will be accepted as correct as long as it is done on the fly by capturing lets say current screen)

Also any pointers towards the right direction would be most welcome , even if they do not constitute a full answer.

A sample image is here

Notice that the characters are greek, and only the big, central letter is required (should i be able to extract all text, that is a bonus, but not an issue if not)

[image]

EDIT: An ideal solution would be about OCR (optical character recognition). Not specifying a language was done to avoid limiting the answers, as any would be acceptable, however my primary choice would be something along the lines of c/c++ due to processing speed.

That being said, any answer that gets to the point (turning this flash 'array' into a 10X10 array of a programming language) with any methodology behind it, would be an acceptable answer. Of course i do not expect a fully working answer for such a complicated issue, strong enough pointers are good enough.

Comment: It's not very clear (at least to me),  are you looking to do OCR (optical character recognition)?  Are looking to do this in flash,  or some other environment?   You need to make your question clearer, and more specific as SO is about specific questions.

Comment: sorry about that, let me rephrase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using actionscript 3 you can load that game swf into another swf that takes a screenshot and saves it to disk, but this would mean breaking the process into two steps with two different languages:

1. take a screenshot via as3
2. process the data via c++

It might be simpler to take the screenshot using c++ and a [system()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) call to take a screenshot. (Feel free to use an Windows specific c++ API for taking screenshots it it makes it easier, but it might be worth keeping your code portable).

Your c++ program can then access the screen and process it for OCR using [OpenCV/Tesseract](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/ddc/classcv_1_1text_1_1OCRTesseract.html#gsc.tab=0)

Comment: Thank you very much, i think this will do the job (as for the screenshot since it is a controlled enviroment i think i will stick to c++ since i can just center it where i want)